# Google таблицы. Выгрузка транзакций с Озона

Tags: google-apps-script

Не могу справится с ошибкой при выгрузке транзакций с озона. В консоли API Ozon работает. При попытке получении данных с помощью кода Google-скрипта выдает ошибку. Ответ сервера:

```
Не удалось получить список начислений: mssql: MarketplaceFinanceTransactionSellerTarifficationListv2: Операция отменена. Не удалось преобразовать строку 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z в дату/время: %!s(MISSING)"
```

Откуда берется нулевое время? Привожу код. При выгрузке атрибутов товара код работает.

```
function transaction() {  
 
    let options = {
    method: "POST",  
      headers:  {  
        'Client-Id':'12345',  
        'API-key':'xxxxxxx',          
        'accept': 'application/json'  
      },  
   "muteHttpExceptions": true,  

    "filter": {  
    "date": {  
  "from": "2020-10-01T07:14:11.897Z",  
              "to": "2020-10-31T07:14:11.897Z"  
},  
        "operation_type": [],  
        "posting_number": "",  
        "transaction_type": "orders"  
    },  
    "page": 1,  
    "page_size": 1000  

    }   
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v3/finance/transaction/list", options);  
}
```

Comment: Это вообще какой язык?

Comment: Google App Script - диалект JavaScript для гугл таблиц и других приложений

Comment: Пишет, что в Дате проблема. Попробуйте заменить даты с текстового варианта на обьект Date.

Comment: Пробовал заменить   "date": {  
  "from": "2020-10-01T07:14:11.897Z",  
              "to": "2020-10-31T07:14:11.897Z"  
}, 
на   var dateFrom = new Date(2021, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  var dateTo = new Date(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    "date": {
  "from": dateFrom,
              "to":dateTo
},
та же ошибка. Такое впечатление что даты совсем не читает , а берет нулевую

Comment: Если это что-то отечественное, то можно проверить типы дат, возможно, вам нужно что-то вроде `2020-10-01T07:14:11+03:00`

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению результат тот же. Интересно что в консоле ОЗОНа  код 
}  
  "filter": {
        "date": {
            "from": "2021-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "to": "2021-11-02T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "operation_type": [],
        "posting_number": "",
        "transaction_type": "all"
    },
    "page": 1,
    "page_size": 1000
}
Работает